# Shadowbox skinning & sizing

Tags: wordpress, shadowbox

How do I skin shadowbox and make sure popup size is fixed size?

The css part is ok since it's just overriding ids and classes.
However, I'm not sure what the `markup.js` is supposed to look.

So here are my questions:

1. I created `shadowbox-custom-skin/markup.js` and added the hook like:

   ```
   add_filter('shadowbox-markup', 'shadowbox_custom_markup');
   ```

   Now I can't find an example of how the `markup.js` is supposed to look.
   (I'm trying to put the `sb-nav` div before the content and the `sb-title` div below the content and also add some new parameters).
2. I fixed the size of the popup using this method:

   ```
   rel="shadowbox;width=480px;height=240px"
   ```

   `handleOversize` `resize` no longer works. Meaning, it will resize content, but it's squeezed.

How do I make sure the popup is the same size, but oversized content isn't squeezed and small content is just centered?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to tweak javascript to do this. Using the property inspector on your browser or the `Firebug` plugin, right click on the `Shadowbox` and see what css classes/ids are being used. Put those css classes/ids in your own stylesheet apply the styles you want. Then upload the file to your server.